# How to create multipage report using Spring?

Tags: spring, jasper-reports, ireport

How do I generate a multipage report in *iReport* where each page contains different invoice of a customer?

Also, each invoice will get its own *datasource* which is the detail as well as a support form of payment.

I've found how to implement a *subreport* here:

http://krams915.blogspot.com/2010/12/spring-3-mvc-jasper-sub-reports-using.html but I don't know how to create the multipage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use page break after subreports. The contents after page break will be displayed in another page .